# What are the main differences between RawArray and PackedArray?

Tags: performance-tuning, undocumented, system, internals

What I know:

- `PackedArray` is documented (to some extent) in "Developer Utilities Package", `RawArray` is just mentioned in `Raster3D` and `ImageApply`,
- `RawArray` supports `Byte`, `SignedInteger8/16/32`, `Bit16`, `Real32`, `Real` and `Complex128` as entries, while `PackedArray` only `Integer`, `Real` and `Complex`(128),
- `PackedArray` displays as a list but `RawArray` as (somewhat of) a skeleton.

What I do not understand is why there are two of them. Why not just stick with the one that supports more entry types and display it as skeleton if and only if it is too long?

Also, how does `ByteArray` fit into the picture?

**Edit**: You can create a `PackedArray` using:

```
ap = Developer`ToPackedArray[{1, 2, 3}]
(* {1,2,3} *)
Developer`PackedArrayQ[ap]
(* True *)
Developer`PackedArrayForm[ap]
(* PackedArray[Integer, <3>] *)
```

(Note that there is in fact no `PackedArray` command, the head of the last output expression is a string.)

You can create a `RawArray` using:

```
ar = Developer`AllocateRawArray["Byte", {2, 2}]
(* RawArray[Byte, <2,2>] *)
Developer`RawArrayQ[ar]
(* True *)
Developer`RawArrayType[ar]
(* Byte *)
```

(ditto about `RawArray`).

You can create a `ByteArray` directly:

```
ab = ByteArray[{1,2,3}]
(* ByteArray[<3>] *)
ByteArrayQ[ab]
(* True *)
```

All the cross-tests (e.g., `RawArrayQ` done on `ab`) return `False`.

Comment: no idea what this means, but according to `ByteCount` both packed and raw arrays use at least 8 bytes per value, even with the "Byte" type explicitly called out.  ByteArray uses the expected one byte per value. The raw array seems to be always *exactly* 96 bytes bigger than the packed array.

Comment: `PackedArray` can't use bytes, 8 bytes is the word size on a 64-bit machine so that makes sense. `RawArray` works well for me: ``ar = Developer`AllocateRawArray["Byte", {10000}]; ByteCount[ar]`` gives just a little over 10000. It's 176 rather than 96 bytes of overhead on my computer.

Comment: I see. I was doing `AllocateRawArray["Byte", *biglist* ]` which is invalid so just getting the size of the list.

Comment: @george2079 instead of `*biglist*` you should use a dimension specification, e.g. `{40,50}` is a `40` by `50` matrix.

Comment: yes i figured that out. I should add on my machine `ByteCount` and `MemoryInUse` indicate hardly any memory usage after "allocating" a large array.

Answer (score 17):

Here goes my conjecture but I would welcome any opinion or clarification by people in the know.

1. `PackedArray` stores data in a **computation-efficient** way. It still represents a `List` in all other respects, and is displayed as one. Some `List`s are generated as `PackedArrays` silently where Mathematica decides it possible and helpful, and unpacked if an operation incompatible with the packing is performed (like changing one element for another of a different type, out of the range of the type, or for a symbolic expression). The reason to store `Integers`, `Reals` and `Complexes` only is that these are natively supported for computation. *The actual size will also depend on the system implementation* (32- or 64-bit). You can perform mathematical operations on a `PackedArray` and it will stay packed and will presumably vectorise the operations where possible.
2. `RawArray` stores data in a **memory-efficient** way in a wide variety of formats that may be useful for different purposes. (Storing a `Byte` instead of a small `Integer` indeed saves a lot of memory (88% on a 64-bit system) but one would need additional CPU instructions in order to calculate with bytes.) It does *not* represent a list as it is considered a zero-depth object: `ar[[1]]` will give an error (and then, unwillingly, tell you it's actually `"Byte"` in the OP example). `ar[[2]]` gives yet another special object called an `ArrayObject` which indeed has no structure as far as Mathematica is concerned. It follows from this that one can't extract data from the `RawArray` using `Part`, and can not perform mathematical operation with these. `RawArray` is ideal for (and is used for) storing *special-purpose data* in objects representing big amounts of very regularly structured information like *bitmap images and sound samples*. Only functions actually designed to deal with the specific kind of data access and modify the information stored inside, otherwise the block of data it represents is **constant**.
3. `ByteArray` is roughly half the way between these: it stores data in a memory-efficient way, with no direct computation, but still representing a list of data which can be accessed directly using `Part`. As opposed to the other two it is limited to a **linear** (one-dimensional) lists and thus perfect for *compressed streams* and the like. It can also be converted to a normal list using `Normal`, like other optimized data structures. It turns out that a `ByteArray` is actually identical to an `ArrayObject[Byte, _]`, but this is not manifested externally. Also, the latter supports a wider selection of types than just `Byte`s.