# Picking first row of a matrix with a positive first element

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, filtering

I have a table of order $30 \times 3$.  I want to pick a row from this table which is first to have its first element to be positive, irrespective of the values of the rest two elements.

For example, if

```
T = {{-2, 1, 2}, {-4, 2, 5}, {-6, 4, 3}, {-2, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 3}}
```

How can I tell Mathematica to pick the row `{2, 4, 4}` from the `T`.

Comment: This works `SelectFirst[T, #[[1]] > 0 &]` which gives (`Out[1]={2, 4, 4}`).

Comment: `Pick[#, Sign[#[[All, 1]]], 1][[1]] &@T`

Answer (score 7):

@Nasser's `FirstCase` gets my vote for speed and simplicity, but different methods will work faster depending on where the first positive first element could show up. Compare the different approaches in this thread along with a new function using `Throw` and `Catch` in a `Do` loop:

```
firstcase[list_] := FirstCase[list, x_ /; Positive[First[x]]] (* Nasser *)

select[list_] := Select[list, First@*Positive, 1][[1]] (* m_goldberg *)

selfirst[list_] := SelectFirst[list, #[[1]] > 0 &] (* ercegovac *)

pick[list_] := Pick[#, Sign[#[[All, 1]]], 1][[1]] &@list (* tomd *)

lenwhile1[list_] := list[[1 + LengthWhile[list[[All, 1]], # <= 0 &]]]; (* kglr *)

lenwhile2[list_] := list[[1 + LengthWhile[list, #[[1]] <= 0 &]]]; (* kglr *)

throwcatch[list_] := Catch@Do[If[list[[i, 1]] > 0, Throw[list[[i]]]], {i, Length[list]}]
```

on two lists:

```
SeedRandom[1]
T1 = RandomInteger[{-5, -1}, {100000, 3}]~Join~{{2, 4, 4}}; (* The "hard" problem *)
T2 = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {100000, 3}]; (* The "easy" problem *)
```

Obviously the first list is "harder", but there are interesting performance differences between the different functions:

```
functions = {firstcase, select, selfirst, pick, lenwhile1, lenwhile2, throwcatch};
res = Map[{First@AbsoluteTiming[#[T1]], First@AbsoluteTiming[#[T2]]} &, functions]

TextGrid[Join[{{"", "T1", "T2"}}, Transpose[
  Join[{{"firstcase", "select", "selfirst", "pick", "lenwhile1", "lenwhile2", "throwcatch"}}, 
  Transpose[res]]]]] // TeXForm
```

\begin{array}{l|l|l}
 \text{} & \text{T1} & \text{T2} \\
 \hline
 \text{firstcase} & 0.104779 & 0.0229505 \\
 \text{select} & 0.177957 & 0.0214707 \\
 \text{selfirst} & 0.12791 & 0.0221214 \\
 \text{pick} & 0.00207038 & 0.00345685 \\
 \hline
 \text{lenwhile1}^* & 0.0588038 & 0.00159609 \\
 \text{lenwhile2}^* & 0.129428 & 0.0000127513 \\
 \text{throwcatch} & 0.108226 & 0.0000205265 \\
\end{array}
${}^*$ Apparently @kglr's `LengthWhile`-based functions run slower on my machine. The free browser version of *Mathematica* 11.2 gets the timings for `lenwhile1 /@ {T1, T2}` to be `{0.04873300, 0.00145900}` and for `lenwhile2 /@ {T1, T2}` to be `{0.09734200, 3.0*10^-6}`. The timings above were obtained on *Mathematica* 11.2 running ion Win10.

The advantage of the `LengthWhile` and `Throw`/`Catch` methods on the easy problem presumably comes from the fact that they explicitly exit when the result is found, although I have no idea how `FirstCase` and `SelectFirst` actually work, so they may be doing a similar thing. `pick` outperforms everything else by an order of magnitude on the hard problem, but for reasons which baffle me, actually takes longer on the easy problem. (`throwcatch` can also be `Compile`d, which increases its speed by another order of magnitude on the easy problem, and two orders of magnitude on the hard problem.)

All of which is just to say that knowing a little about the structure of the problem can help make a choice about the best algorithm to tackle it. Of course, in the OP's example there were only 30 elements, so all this is kind of moot...

Comment: And maybe include `Pick[#, Sign[#[[All, 1]]], 1][[1]] &@T1` ?

Comment: Does mma performs any kind of optimization when storing a list with many same elements?

Comment: aardvark2012,  i replaced  `lenwhile`  with two versions.

Comment: @tomd Done. Sorry I missed it first time around.

Comment: @ercegovac I know very little about how _Mathematica_ works under the surface, but you might find [what-are-the-main-differences-between-rawarray-and-packedarray](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110170/what-are-the-main-differences-between-rawarray-and-packedarray) useful for intensive data storage.

Comment: @kglr Included the new `lenwhile`, but didn't get the same timings. Particularly for the hard case. No idea what's going on there.

Comment: thank you aardvark. Somehow, the numbers on your table  for `lenwhile1` and `lenwhile2` are quite different from what i am getting (on  the free browser version of mma 11.2.)

Comment: @kglr Re-ran everything on MMA 11.2 and got substantial improvements in the `LengthWhile` functions. Still not the times you were getting, but closer.

Comment: You might want to consider adding `Catch[Scan[If[Positive[First[#]], Throw[#]] &, mat]]` to your rankings.

Comment: @J.M. I tried that, but it's weirdly slow (0.20 for hard and 0.02 for easy). It seemed to me that it should be faster than the `Do`/`Catch` one, and I had no good explanation for why it wasn't, so I left it off.

Comment: @aardvark, huh. Yeah, that is a shock for me... oh well.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[lenwhile1, lenwhile2]
lenwhile1 = #[[1 + LengthWhile[#[[All, 1]], # <= 0 &]]] &;
lenwhile2 = #[[1 + LengthWhile[#, #[[1]] <= 0 &]]] &;

lenwhile1 @ T
```

> {2, 4, 4}

```
lenwhile1 @ T == lenwhile2 @ T
```

> True

**Timings:**

Using aardvark2012's setup with

```
functions = {firstcase, lenwhile1, lenwhile2, pick, select, selfirst, throwcatch};
```

where

```
pick =  Pick[#, Sign[#[[All, 1]]], 1][[1]] &;
```

is suggested by tomd in a comment.

```
SeedRandom[1]
T1 = RandomInteger[{-5, -1}, {100000, 3}]~Join~{{2, 4, 4}};
T2 = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {100000, 3}];
```

[image]

```
Equal @@ (#[T1]& /@ functions)
```

> True

```
Equal @@ (#[T2]& /@ functions)
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use `FirstCase`

```
T0 = {{-2,1,2},{-4,2,5},{-6,4,3},{-2,2,1},{2,4,4},{1,5,3}};
FirstCase[ T0, x_/; Positive[First[x]]  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
T = {{-2, 1, 2}, {-4, 2, 5}, {-6, 4, 3}, {-2, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 3}}
Select[T, First@*Positive, 1][[1]]
```

> `{2, 4, 4}`